# How to remove duplicate JOINs from a query without doing it manually?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The different parts of the query is collected from different variables in the program to form the final query,

```
$start= "SELECT co.name FROM common co";
$fjoin="";
$qwhere= "WHERE fruit=banana";

IF ($fruits==1)
{
$fjoin.= "INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number";
}
IF ($apple==1)
{
$fjoin.= "INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number";
}
IF ($banana==1)
{
$fjoin.= "LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack";
}

$all=$start.$fjoin.$qwhere;
```

so when program is run $all=SELECT co.name FROM common co INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack WHERE fruit=banana

The user is given three options fruit, banana and apple, if user chooses fruit $fruit becomes 1 and if user chooses banana $banana becomes 1 and if user chooses apple $apple becomes 1. User can choose both fruit and banana or all options fruit banana and apple. When user chooses all options $all has a duplicate INNER JOIN as seen above (INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number is a dupicate join). How to check for duplicate JOINS in the final query which is the variable $all and remove it. Does anybody know how to identify duplicate JOINS and remove them?

I used $fjoin= implode('INNER JOIN',array_unique(explode('INNER JOIN', $fjoin))); to remove the duplicate INNER JOIN but the above command is unable to separate INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack and hence it says no duplicates found :(

I was thinking of adding a comma after every join and then using this statement $fjoin= implode(' ',array_unique(explode(',', $fjoin))); this might work but I have too many JOIN statements in my program to go back in and add commas so was wondering if there is a way to do this with some simple remove duplicate JOINS command

Comment: why use + in place of . ?

Comment: Store in an array instead of a string, call `array_unique` on it before building the final query at the end.

Comment: @Gunner oops I meant . just edited it

Comment: @Wrikken I used $fjoin= implode('INNER JOIN',array_unique(explode('INNER JOIN', $fjoin))); to remove the duplicate INNER JOIN but the above command is unable to separate INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack and hence it says no duplicates found :(

Comment: That's why I seard to _store in an array instead of a string_. Not to crowbar it back into an array later on. (You can do this, but it's iffy. The mean reason is you should add 1 trailing space to your split string probably (`"INNER JOIN "`), 1 single character difference, even whitespace, matters at that point). But that may still not work as you seem to have no trailing spaces in your `JOIN`  conditions.

Comment: @Wrikken I was thinking of adding a comma after every join and then using this statement $fjoin= implode('',array_unique(explode(',', $fjoin))); this might work but I have too many JOIN statements in my program to go back in and add commas so was wondering if there is a way to do this with some simple remove duplicate JOINS command

Comment: Whats wrong with using `$join = array();` & `$join[] = ` instead of 1 $join = '';` & `$join .= ` ? A lot easier.

Comment: @Wrikken thanks buddy but changing the string to array involves changing the way I have programmed the rest of the program so adding a comma after every JOIN statement is easier in comparison to changing string to array if I come think of it.

Comment: So, you have to add a comma _on every single JOIN line_, but changing it to array (= a whopping **2** extra chars in those lines) is a bridge to far? Damn, well, good luck. I hope there isn't a comma already there in any `JOIN` statement, or you'll have to find another delimiter :)

Comment: @Wrikken Haahaa I have not shared my entire code this is a dumbed-down version I have made operations that can be performed only on strings on those variables if I change it to an array I have to change all those operations too hence adding a marker like a comma after JOINS is easier. Thanks for your thoughts though. I appreciate it.

Comment: OK, _do_ choose another delimiter then a comma though, those could be valid in some join conditions. Best to choose a delimiter that is not part of the SQL syntax, and is also unlikely to occur in possible strings / values in that join condition. A vertical tab or something, those would be rare. Define the delimiter somewhere as a constant, and use that in the code, to avoid having to change the delimiter at every single location if you run into conflicts and need to change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverted to my idea of adding a marker '|' after every join and then using this statement $fjoin= implode(' ',array_unique(explode('|', $fjoin))); and it worked. Thanks All!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem here is that your conditions are wrong. You're setting the variable, not evaluating it.

You have `if ($fruits = 1)` which always **sets** the value of `$fruits` to `1`, so the condition will always be `true`. Use `==` to evaluate if the variable is equal to the value.

You can read more about PHP's comparison operators here: http://php.net/ternary

**EDIT**: I'm adding an alternative here since you've corrected your question.

Store your joins in an array and then use `array_unique()` to remove the duplicates:

```
$joins = array();

if ($fruits == 1) {
  $joins[] = "INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number";
}
if ($apple == 1) {
  $joins[] = "INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number";
}
if ($banana == 1) {
  $joins[] = "LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack";
}

$joins = array_unique($joins);
```

If all conditions were to evaluate as true your resulting array will have the duplicates removed and look like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number
    [2] => LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack
)
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question.  It's just typos in the dumbed-down example.

Comment: Then he needs to remove typo's from his question. Evaluating `if ($fruits = 1)` will cause exactly the problem he is having - a duplicate join.

Comment: Oh, I see.  Yes, it's true that his typos will mean that all the joins will be added all the time, currently resulting in duplicates every time.  But if you had the same typos in my solution or Wrikken's solution, it would not result in duplicates, just in unwanted extra joins.  That's why my brain concluded it was off-topic.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I handle this kind of thing.  I make a map array of the possible join tables with the keys being the names of the tables.  I do this map so there is no re-typing of the joins, reducing the chances of typos.  I then collect an array of the joins out of this map.  Because they have the same key in the collection array, they can't be added twice.  Finally, I implode the collection array into a string.

```
$start= "SELECT co.name FROM common co";
$qwhere= "WHERE fruit=banana";

$map = array(
     'fruits'=>"INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number",
     'banana'=>"LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack"
     );
$joins = array();

if($fruit==1) {
     $joins['fruits'] = $map['fruits'];
}
if($apple==1) {
     $joins['fruits'] = $map['fruits'];
}
if($banana==1) {
     $joins['banana'] = $map['banana'];
}

$all = $start . (implode(" ", $joins)) . $qwhere;
```

Answer (score 0):

So obvious that I must be missing something :)

```
if ($fruits == 1 || $apple == 1)
{
    $fjoin.= "INNER JOIN fruits fu ON fu.number = co.number";
}
if ($banana == 1) {
    fjoin .= "LEFT OUTER JOIN banana ba ON ba.pack = fu.pack";
}
```